# Putting Jailbroken iPad 1 into DFU mode

Tags: ipad

I have a jailbroken iPad1 that is still using iOS 4.  I want to upgrade it to iOS 5, but I cannot get it to go into DFU mode in order to do so.  Can anyone identify the exact steps needed to either put the iPad into DFU mode, or upgrade via a different method?

Answer (score 1):

1. Plug the iPad into your computer
2. Launch iTunes
   (turn of your iPad)
3. Hold down the Power button and the Home button at the same time
4. Keep holding both of these buttons for 10 seconds
5. After 10 seconds pass, release the Power button but continue to hold the Home button for another 3-5 seconds
6. When in DFU mode, your iPad screen will stay completely black. If you see an Apple logo or otherwise you did not enter DFU mode
7. iTunes will notify you that it has detected a device in recovery mode

Answer (score 0):

the awnser above is correct, however you dont need to put it in DFU just plug it in and upgrade, if you want to download the manually "[iOS manual download](http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/)" "[how to](http://iphoners.org/shift-restore.itunes/)" you have to put it in DFU and provided apple still signs the os,  however as i said, just plug it in iTunes and you'll be able to upgrade it straight from iTunes